# How to create SVG icons and how to implement on web applications?

Tags: html, css, svg, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How to create SVG icons and how to implement the SVG icons on our web application? Can you please anyone help to create and implement on web application?

Comment: You tagged this as Adobe Illustrator... that's a good tool for creating vector art which you can save as SVG.  Did you have a technical question?

Comment: While you can create your own icons in adobe-illustrator, you must know that you can choose between lots of icons already made. This is one place where to look [Icons - Material Design - Material.io](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) or https://thenounproject.com/. There are many places where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adobe-illustrator, too. There you can simply export SVG Files. In HTML you just reference your SVG-File simply in the src attribute of an  tag. For example:

```
<img src="assets/icons/icon.svg" class="icon" alt="icon">
```

To set the size in CSS you just edit the height and width of the image, for example:

```
.icon{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

When your not good at designing just search for free to use icons or logos maybe you'll find something you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use D3.js, which is a library you can use to add and manipulate SVG objects: https://d3js.org/

A simple very simple example of implementation would look like this:

```js
d3.select('#container')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('height', 400)
  .attr('width', 400)


d3.select('svg')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 100)
  .attr('y', 100)
  .attr('height', 400)
  .attr('width', 400)
  .attr('fill', 'black')
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Sample SVG</h1>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This adds an SVG object to the container div then adds a black square to the SVG. Although, this library is primarily for data visualization and may not be exactly what you are looking for.